# How to remove the value from array which is same as index?

Tags: php, arrays

How to remove the value 58 from the array.

```
[58] => Array // <- key here
    (
        [0] => 58 // <- match value here
        [1] => 59
        [2] => 61
        [3] => 67
    )
```

In the array above the main array key (58) matches the subarray value of key 0.
I want the array result to be:

```
[58] => Array
    (
        [1] => 59
        [2] => 61
        [3] => 67
    )
```

Comment: Do you have multiple indexes like 58 (which also have a sub array) also share whatever you have tried ?

Comment: your question is not clear ..

Comment: No, the index is unique. I am new to php so i haven't tried much.

Comment: is the value `58` always the first element?

Comment: @scaisEdge I have an array with the index 58, Now,  If there are any values inside my array with 58. I want to remove it? how to do that

Comment: @Thamaraiselvam Nope it can be anywhere

Comment: i have already posted an answer   ..

Comment: @SathishM Do you want the filtered output to be re-indexed? or do you want to preserve the original keys? or doesn't it matter?  Andreas' question edit assumes you want to preserve the keys.

Comment: @SathishM  it's your responsibility to check all answers and mark+up-vote one answer which is most suitable to you. You can up-vote others too if they are useful too.  This will helps future visitors to get their answers easily and quickly.Thanks

Comment: While this question is not what I consider "complete" (because there is no proof of effort/research), the desired functionality is clear.

Answer (score 3):

Assumed that your array have multiple indexes like 58,59,60....

You need to do it like below:-

```
 foreach($array as $key => $val){
   if(is_array($val)){

     $k = array_search($key,$val);
     if($k ===false){
     }else{
       unset($array[$key][$k]);
     }
   }

 }
print_r($array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/853076 (single-dimensional array)   OR https://eval.in/853081 (multi-dimensional array)

Reference:-

[PHP unset() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)

[PHP array_search() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: https://3v4l.org/OHY11 removes an key even if it's not found.

Comment: @Andreas  thanks for telling. Corrected that

Answer (score 1):

If you want remove the entry for $array[58] you can use unset

```
 unset($array[58]); // this remove all the subarray (index 0,1,2,3)
```

if you want remove the entry 0 for $array[58] you can use

```
 unset($array[58][0]);// this remove only index 0 of subarray
```

otherwise if you need  to remove based on content  you must search over the content

```
if(($key = array_search($array[58], 58)) !== false) {
   unset($array[58][$key]);
}
```

Comment: I dono the index value of 58. I just know the value. In that case how to do that

Comment: answer  updated ..

Answer (score 0):

Using `array_search()`, you can get the keys of an array where you look for a "needle in a haystack". That means you can find the values where it matches the arrays key. Then it's just a matter of removing that element, using `unset()`. Then loop over and apply the functions above, it'd look like this. We check that the `array_search()` doesn't return a boolean false (which is why we use typecomparison `===`, or in this case, `!==`). If we just checked for a false value, it wouldn't remove the value if it had index `0`, as that's a falsy value.

```
$array = array(58 => array(
            0 => 58,
            1 => 59,
            2 => 61,
            3 => 67
        ),
        59 => array(
            0 => 58,
            1 => 59,
            2 => 61,
            3 => 67
        ));

foreach ($array as $key=>$value) {
    if ($remove_keys = array_search($key, $value) !== false)
        unset($array[$key][$remove_keys]);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [58] => Array
        (
            [1] => 59
            [2] => 61
            [3] => 67
        )

    [59] => Array
        (
            [0] => 58
            [2] => 61
            [3] => 67
        )

)
```

As you can see, all the sub-arrays have their elements removed that match the index of that array.

- [Live demo](https://3v4l.org/3bLbm)
- [PHP.net on `unset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php)
- [PHP.net on `array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: Because there is no `if` statement to check for `array_search()`'s possible `false`, this method removes the first element element from a subarray if the key is not found in the subarray.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/72270957d38e40615576fc2d6a55e1847aeb7d4e

Comment: You're absolutely right, @mickmackusa, I missed that. I've updated the answer to reflect that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Loop with foreach and use array_search to find the key of matching number.

```
$arr["58"] = Array
(
    "0" => 58,
    "1" => 59,
    "2" => 61,
    "3" => 67
);



Foreach($arr as $key => &$subarr){
    $find = array_search($key, $subarr);
    If($find !== false){
        unset($subarr[$find]);
    }
}

Var_dump($arr);
```

https://3v4l.org/4gYIo

Answer (score 0):

I think `array_diff()` is most concise, it doesn't need to check for true or false, it just filters it out if the key exists in the subarray, and if it doesn't exist it just moves on quietly.  It has the added feature of being able to remove all occurrences of the key in the subarray in one action.  My method modifies `$a` (the subarray) by reference.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TOnlQ))

```
$array = [
    58 => [58, 59, 61, 67],
    59 => [58, 60, 61],
    60 => [59, 60, 60, 60, 61]
];

foreach ($array as $k => &$a) {
    $a = array_diff($a, [$k]);  // key is written as a single-element array
}
var_export($array);
```

Output:

```
array (
  58 => 
  array (
    1 => 59,
    2 => 61,
    3 => 67,
  ),
  59 => 
  array (
    0 => 58,
    1 => 60,
    2 => 61,
  ),
  60 => 
  array (
    0 => 59,
    4 => 61,
  ),
)
```

...if you want to have zero-indexed subarrays, you can just add `array_values()` like this: `$a = array_values(array_diff($a, [$k]));`

Answer (score -1):

If you have a multidimentional array of, let's say, N elements with M items inside (where N and M are integers > 0) and you want to apply this to all of it you can do:

```
foreach($array as $key => $subarray) {
    if (($subkey = array_search($key, $subarray)) !== false) {
        if (is_array($subkey)) {
            foreach ($subkey as $idx) {
                unset($array[$key][$idx]);
            }
        } else {
            unset($array[$key][$subkey]);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to have the keys of the subarrays as a correct zero index you can add inside the if

```
$array[$key] = array_values($array[$key]);
```